# Are module finite algebras over semiperfect rings again semiperfect?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, noncommutative-rings, local-rings

Let $S$ be a Noetherian semiperfect ring (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring). Let $R$ be a module finite associative $S$-algebra. Then, is $R$ also a semiperfect ring? (Clearly, $R$ is Noetherian). If this is not true in general, what if I also assumed $S$ is commutative?

Comment: Previously posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833652).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, even if $S$ is commutative. There may be easier counterexamples, but ...

There are commutative Noetherian local (and therefore semiperfect) rings $S$ with a finitely generated indecomposable module $M$ whose endomorphism ring is not local. For example, in

*Evans, E. Graham jun.*, [**Krull-Schmidt and cancellation over local rings**](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1973.46.115), Pac. J. Math. 46, 115-121 (1973). [ZBL0272.13006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0272.13006).

an example due to Swan is given.

Let $R=\operatorname{End}_S(M)$, and let
$\operatorname{add}(M)$ be the category of direct summands of finite direct sums of copies of $M$.

The functor $\operatorname{Hom}_S(M, -)$ is an equivalence of categories from $\operatorname{add}(M)$ to the category of finitely generated projective right $R$-modules.

Since $\operatorname{add}(M)$ does not satisfy the Krull-Schmidt theorem, neither does the category of finitely generated projective right $R$-modules. But the category of finitely generated projectives for a semiperfect ring does satisfy the Krull-Schmidt theorem, so $R$ is not semiperfect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... could you please explain why $add(M)$ does not satisfy Krull-Schmidt?

Comment: @uno To satisfy Krull-Schmidt means that every object is a finite direct sum of indecomposable objects with local endomorphism rings. But $M$ is indecomposable and doesn’t have a local endomorphism ring. See [Krull-Schmidt category](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_category).